# Change center of map according to autocomplete input using google maps codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having difficulties on getting the center of the map when I use 'placesautocompleteonchange' of google maps codeigniter library.

First, as the page loads, the center of the map is set to a specific city (which is I specified)
    `$config['center'] = '8.457348645837307,124.63308727385254';`

then I specified some configurations to activate autocomplete function.

```
   `$config['places'] = TRUE;
    $config['placesAutocompleteInputID'] = 'address';
    $config['placesAutocompleteBoundsMap'] = TRUE;`
```

then I also add a marker configuration

```
    `$marker = array();
    $marker['draggable'] = true;`
```

my problem is, I don't know how to change the center of the map according to the inputted address on my input field and change the location of the marker according to the current center of the map.

I hope someone can help me. thank you

(sorry for my bad english)

P.S: I used Sir BIOSTALL's Google Maps V3 Codeigniter Library

Answer (score 0):

**You** *simply* need to get the input using `$this->input->post()` and then combine both values with `explode` into a string

*For more assistance please read*

1. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/
2. http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/placesautocomplete

---

```
$center = implode(',', array(
     $this->input->post('lat'),
     $this->input->post('lon')
));

$config['center'] = $center;
$marker['position'] = $center;
```